# Rest Easy with Spring Boot getting 404 Response

Tags: spring-boot, resteasy

I have configured Rest easy in my spring boot application . I have excluded DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class in my configuration class because I was getting different error . Everything is configured properly , But when I tried to make a post call I'm getting 404 response. Further investigation showed me that request is success as I have written a syso inside respective method and is getting printed also ,but I'm getting 404 response .  I have tried with rest easy spring boot starter and also created bean manually using spring annotations.In both I'm getting same response .Can anyone please help me with this . If needed I can share my code also.

Comment: After exploring the logs I got the following exception                                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.setDefaultContentType(ServerResponseWriter.java:310)
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:55)
 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:473)

Comment: I'm using both dispatcher servlet and rest easy .But both are with different url pattern